# how to include extra static file(css,js) with velocity when I use a layout.vm?

Tags: java, velocity

I got a `layout.vm` like this

```
<html> 
<head>
  <title>$!page_title</title>
  <link href="path/to/css.css">
</head>
<body>
  $screen_content
  <script src="path/to/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is a `user.vm` need to be render with `layout.vm`

```
#set($page_title="User") 
<div>hello, user.vm</div>
```

but the `user.vm` need more js/css file
and I want the render result will like this

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>User</title>
  <link href="path/to/css.css">
  <link href="path/to/user.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>hello, user.vm</div>
  <script src="path/to/js.js"></script>
  <script src="path/to/user.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare another var in `user.vm`:

```
#set($isUser = true)
```

Now edit `layout.vm`. There are two options. If you want to use just one stylesheet then toggle them like this:

```
<head>
  <title>$!page_title</title>
  #if($isUser)
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/user.css">
  #else
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css.css">
  #end
</head>
```

Or overwrite styles like this

```
<head>
  <title>$!page_title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css.css">
  #if($isUser)<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/user.css">#end
</head>
```

Do the same with your scripts. If you put them in the head section you could even do that in one check.

Note: You could do almost the same by checking if `$!page_title` equals 'User', but that's not the best idea, because you overload the meaning of the var. Hence, I'd suggested to use another.

Also note: This solution works completely inside Velocity. If you are using backing objects anyway you should use them (in general) to declare and set the var(s).

Tested in Velocity 1.7